# Xmonad defaults deprecation: what is the future proof configuration?

Tags: xmonad

This may be borderline between here an SO since a lot of the question is about haskell programming.  Yet, in the end, it is a configuration issue.

#### Background and research

Since 0.12 Xmonad throws this warning (several times) in xmonad.errors:

```
xmonad.hs:15:14: warning: [-Wdeprecations]
    In the use of ‘defaultConfig’
    (imported from XMonad, but defined in XMonad.Config):
    Deprecated: "Use def (from Data.Default, and re-exported by XMonad and XMonad.Config) instead."
```

And it works, it is just a warning.  Yet, I'd like to understand what is causing the warning (I'm trying to understand it and failing at it for several hours already).  By the deprecation description you'd guess that `XMonad.Config` is not using the definition of `Default` from `Data.Default`, but that is not the case.  Looking at the code of [`XMonad.Config`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.12/docs/src/XMonad-Config.html) you see at the beginning the import:

```
import XMonad.Core as XMonad hiding
    (workspaces,manageHook,keys,logHook,startupHook,borderWidth,mouseBindings
    ,layoutHook,modMask,terminal,normalBorderColor,focusedBorderColor,focusFollowsMouse
    ,handleEventHook,clickJustFocuses,rootMask,clientMask)
import qualified XMonad.Core as XMonad
    (workspaces,manageHook,keys,logHook,startupHook,borderWidth,mouseBindings
    ,layoutHook,modMask,terminal,normalBorderColor,focusedBorderColor,focusFollowsMouse
    ,handleEventHook,clickJustFocuses,rootMask,clientMask)

import XMonad.Layout
import XMonad.Operations
import XMonad.ManageHook
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import Data.Bits ((.|.))
import Data.Default
import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Map as M
import System.Exit
import Graphics.X11.Xlib
import Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras
```

And `Data.Default` is definitely there.  Then `defaultConfig` (still inside `Xmonad.Config`) is defined as:

```
instance (a ~ Choose Tall (Choose (Mirror Tall) Full)) => Default (XConfig a) where
  def = XConfig
    { XMonad.borderWidth        = borderWidth
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
    , XMonad.rootMask           = rootMask
    , XMonad.handleExtraArgs = \ xs theConf -> case xs of
                [] -> return theConf
                _ -> fail ("unrecognized flags:" ++ show xs)
    }

-- | The default set of configuration values itself
{-# DEPRECATED defaultConfig "Use def (from Data.Default, and re-exported by XMonad and XMonad.Config) instead." #-}
defaultConfig :: XConfig (Choose Tall (Choose (Mirror Tall) Full))
defaultConfig = def
```

So `defaultConfig` should be using `Data.Default`, and I am the one doing something wrong, probably.

---

#### Solution attempts

My minimal configuration (`xmonad.hs`) that is throwing the warning is:

```
import XMonad

main = xmonad defaultConfig { terminal = "urxvt" }
```

(My full xmonad configuration is huge, the above is just a minimal config that replicates the warning.)

I tried:

```
import Data.Default
import XMonad

main = xmonad defaultConfig { terminal = "urxvt" }
```

But the warning remains.  I could use `main = xmonad XConfig {}` and then enumerate every configuration option, but that would be copying 90% of `XMonad.Config` into my own `xmonad.hs`.

---

#### Question

What am I doing wrong?  How do I force the use of `Data.Default`?  Did I understood the deprecation warning correctly in the first place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need import `import Data.Default`

this is imported in XMonad itself

only one change is needed:

```
import XMonad
main = xmonad defaultConfig { terminal = "urxvt" }
```

to

```
import XMonad
main = xmonad def { terminal = "urxvt" }
```

Comment: It works!  I can't believe it was that stupid a mistake that i did.  In the end I used `import qualified XMonad.Config as DefConfig` and then `DefConfig.def` in every place with `defaultConfig`.  Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I just couldn't parse the message. From too much Ruby, "def" was a keyword and I just didn't _see_ it as an option to write instead of "defaultConfig".